# Python 3. Extract data from json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

How to extract 41677?

My json:

```
{"41677":{"key":"ilya","premium":"true"}}
```

My code:

```
params={"id": "ilya", "fmt": "json"}
r=requests.get("somesite", params=params )
data=json.loads(r.text)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `loads`, your JSON string will be converted to a dictionary which maps keys to values.

Since you need the key `41677`, you can simply call `data.keys()[0]` to retrieve the first key of your dictionary.

EDIT:

Also, if you have a list of that JSON structure, you can iterate over the keys and values using the `items` function, like so:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    print key  # 41677
    print value  # {"key":"ilya","premium":"true"}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using Requests' built-in json attribute:

```
data = requests.get("somesite", params=params ).json().keys()[0]
```

assuming the json it returns is {"41677":{"key":"ilya","premium":"true"}}:

```
>>>print data
"41677"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
s = {"41677":{"key":"ilya","premium":"true"}}
d = json.dumps(s)
l = json.loads(d)
l.keys()
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code. Explain why this is an answer!